What is the problem of short circuitting here?
books is an array with objects nested inside.
What I want to achieve is: (in the traditional way)
if (i.thirdParty.goodreads.rating < 4.2) {
i.highlighted = false;
}

Now I am learning short circuit, which as said it can be written as
for (const i of books) {
  i.highlighted = i.thirdParty.goodreads.rating < 4.2 && false;
}

However, I worte it in another way and really do not understand why isn't it working
for (const i of books) {
  i.thirdParty.goodreads.rating < 4.2 && i.highlighted = false;
}


Can someone tell me what is the problem here, thank you

&& is part of the expression after the =, not the whole statement

The error you screenshotted is from your linter, not the runtime. Try actually running the code and see if it works.

@dragoncoder047 It won't. That's a syntax error.

Just use an if.  That way it will be easy to understand for the next person who maintains this code.  If that next person is you several years from now, you will appreciate how you made it easy for yourself.

The = operator expects a variable or property on the left-hand side, not a boolean expression. That is why you are getting a syntax error.
If you want to maintain that current pattern, you can do something like this and wrap the assignment in parantheses, but in my opinion, you are sacrificing readability.
for (const i of books) {
  i.thirdParty.goodreads.rating < 4.2 && (i.highlighted = false);
}

To explain, if i.thirdParty.goodreads.rating < 4.2 evaluates to true, it will perform the assignment to i.highlight.
